# Multiple App Debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, android-sdk-tools

I have an issue that I cannot find a solution for. I am developing two different Android apps that are a part of a larger project. The one thing they have in common is the same package name.

So my manifest looks like this for each project:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.test" android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0">
```

Both apps works fine, but when I debug App 1, it overwrites App 2 on the device. Then when I try to debug App 2, I get this error:

```
New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.test/.RegistrationActivity }
ActivityManager: Error type 3
ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.test/com.test.RegistrationActivity} does not exist.
```

Where `RegistrationAcitvity` is the `Activity` I am launching when the app starts.

I have found that if I **clean** App 2, then it installs and launches correctly. However, when this is done, App 1 no longer shows up on the device. Oddly enough, I am always able to launch App 1 from Eclipse, but after doing so I am back to the error above, which can again be fixed by **clean** on App 2.

The other strange thing that may or may not have something to do with this is the fact that every time I launch App 1, Eclipse automatically chooses the device I have plugged in. However, when I launch App 2, Eclipse *always* prompts me to choose a device. And yes, the **deployment target** option in the debug configuration is set to **automatic** -- I'm not sure if this is related or not.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name for Android packages need to be unique.

> A full Java-language-style package name for the application. The name
> should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters
> ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual
> package name parts may only start with letters.
>
> To avoid conflicts
> with other developers, you should use Internet domain ownership as the
> basis for your package names (in reverse). For example, applications
> published by Google start with com.google. You should also never use
> the com.example namespace when publishing your applications.
>
> The
> package name serves as a unique identifier for the application. It's
> also the default name for the application process (see the
>  element's process process attribute) and the default
> task affinity of an activity (see the  element's
> taskAffinity attribute).

[source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

Comment: I thought I read that each app was in its own sandbox. I guess I was under the assumption that package names were private to the app. I used "com.test" in my example for the sake of simplicity. Thanks for your help!